# find inherited properties of a generic list elements using reflection

Tags: c#, list, generics, reflection, properties

I have a generic List as:

```
IList<BaseEntity> list; //base entity is a public base class
```

also i have some other classes that inherited from `BaseEntity`:

```
public class Order:BaseEntity
{
    //Properties
}
public class Customer:BaseEntity
{
    //Properties
}
....
public class X:BaseEntity
{
    //Properties
}
```

my list filled with these inherited objects(`Order`,`Customer`,...).
how can i find all properties of each element(include `BaseEntity` properties and inherited properties) in `list` using reflection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every object in the .net world provides you with `GetType` method, so for every element in the list you can ask it for the set of its properties:

```
foreach(var item in list)
{
    var props = item.GetType().GetProperties();
    // props is a PropertyInfo[]
}
```

Each PropertyInfo carries many information like the PropertyName, the PropertyType(that is, what the Getter returns) and the DefinedBy (that is, which class defined it -- it may be this class or any base class of the inquired object).

See [GetProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/aky14axb.aspx). By default it returns only public properties, but considering you say 'entity' this will probably be what you want. But, if you need nonpublic properties too, then see  [GetProperties(BindingFlags)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx).

Please note that this actually inquires each object in the list about its own properties. You will get N arrays of various properties **of classes**, not objects. If the 5th item is a Foo, then you will get an array of PropInfos for Foo class.

This not necessarily is the best way, as most probably the object types will be repeated in your list. You may want to first scan the list for distinct types and then inquire for properties only once per type.

Answer (score 2):

You can get all public properties of each object like this:

```
foreach (var e in list) {
    var type = e.GetType();
    Console.WriteLine("====== {0}", type.FullName);
    foreach (var p in type.GetProperties()) {
        Console.WriteLine(p);
    }
}
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/hNZjVl). `GetProperties()` produces a list of all public properties of your class. You can examine the names and the types of these properties using the `PropertyInfo` variable `p`. You can also get and set the properties themselves by calling `var val = p.GetValue(e)`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this for each item in the list:

item.GetType().GetProperties() or the GetProperties overload:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperties.aspx